# What is the simplest $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ function with two peaks and a valley?

Tags: functions, polynomials, graphing-functions, exponential-function, applications

What is the simplest $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ function with two peaks and a valley?

I have a set of points in $\Bbb{R^2}$ and I would like to fit a curve to the points, the points approximately lie on a curve like the one depicted in the following figure:

[image: A $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ function with two peaks and a valley.]

My points are such that $a$ (the width of the valley) is almost constant while $b$ (the height of the peaks with respect to the valley) can change.

My informal definition of "simplest" is based on the following requirements:

1. the function should be sufficient smooth
2. the fit should be easy to do with some off-the-shelf algorithm
3. I have just the points lying on the curve in figure, so I think that the function should smoothly go to zero to the left of the left peak and to the right of the right peak.

My goal is to estimate $b$.

Comment: I'm not sure, but would the folks at [cross-validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) know better about this? I mean, choosing an appropriate fitting function. I'm sure we could all come up with examples, but I have no idea what pitfalls exist.

Comment: I have no idea about what the shelf algorithm is, but just looking at the picture I'd hope to find a polynomial that of degree $4$ that fits it. The reason is that the derivative of the function is equal to $0$ three times.

Comment: You might want to look into a [bimodal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bimodal_distribution).

Comment: It could be helpful what kind of measurement/physical experiment is behind the data gathering. Is the function supposed to be symmetric? What makes you think that it goes to zero as $|x|\to\infty$?

Comment: @GitGud I edited the post, I was meaning a "standard" and largely available algorithm, not some particular exotic one.

Comment: As Git Gud points out, a quartic fit could do the job here, since you could have $3$ local extrema (two peaks and a valley). This is also a standard kind of algorithm.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen You can think at the curve as the cross section of a plastic part. For what regard the symmetry: if I put a reference system $xy$ on the curve and $x=0$ is at the bottom of the valley then it should be $f(-x)=f(x)$.

Comment: @uvts_cvs According to your comment the curve should model a bent plastic stick. That would suggest that "stress" is (locally) minimized. Such a situation is (for not so large deformations) often modeled with *cubic* equations. As your shape requirements don't match that, it seems there is something inherently unstable in it. Indeed, if I try to bend a sheet of paper to show a cross section like your drawing the situation is very delicate: The paper tries to bulge down ever more or - if I force it up just slightly - it suddenly flips to a simpler one-bulge shape ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say that you "*think that the function should smoothly go to zero to the left of the left peak and to the right of the right peak*", notice that it *does not have to*. Moreover, both $a$ and $b$ can be chosen arbitrarily.

The easiest way to do this would be to take a polynomial. If you want the simplest polynomial with two maxima at $(\pm\!\tfrac{1}{2}a,b)$ and one minimum at $(0,0)$, then
$$\operatorname{f}(x) = \frac{8b}{a^4}(a^2-2x^2)x^2$$

If you insist the function to tend to zero then you need to edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to go to zero at $\pm \infty$, how about $(dx^2+f)\exp(-cx^2)$?  Very smooth, easy to calculate, shaped like you want.